# Hashed Id for device to test facebookAds?

Tags: ios, hash

I want to know the hashed device id for testing the facebook Ads. We can get it in console but it would be great if we can get via programming and add devices for facebook Ad testing since I want to get the device without hard code the hashed device Id evertime

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** The `FBAudienceNetwork` framework has been updated, and the correct way to get the device hash is to do so programmatically:

```
NSString *deviceHash = [FBAdSettings testDeviceHash];
```

It looks like the device hash isn't even logged to the console anymore, so contrary to my original answer below, this is now the only way to go.

---

**Original answer:** I think Facebook's goal is to prevent developers from releasing an app that will show test ads. By forcing you to copy the test device hash from the console for each test device, they automatically limit the devices that show test ads to those that you're actually using. If you could get the hash programmatically you'd be able to show test ads on every device.

Short answer: **It looks like you can't get the device hash programmatically.**

Comment: any idea how to get it without the console? my device is not able to connect to my computer

Comment: Do you know perhaps for Android too?